# Pipe ResponseSpec's Body

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I'm writing a utility method which pipes given `ResponseSpec`'s body and gives to the caller a change to read it.

```
static <R> Mono<R> pipeBodyAndApply(
        final WebClient.ResponseSpec spec,
        final ExecutorService executor,
        final Function<? super ReadableByteChannel, ? extends R> function) {
    return using(
            Pipe::open,
            p -> {
                final Future<Disposable> future = executor.submit(
                        () -> write(spec.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class), p.sink())
                                .log()
                                .doFinally(s -> {
                                    try {
                                        p.sink().close();
                                        log.debug("p.sink closed");
                                    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                                    }
                                })
                                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())
                );
                return just(function.apply(p.source()))
                        .log()
                        .doFinally(s -> {
                            try {
                                final Disposable disposable = future.get();
                                assert disposable.isDisposed();
                            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {                                 e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
            },
            p -> {
                try {
                    p.source().close();
                    log.debug("p.source closed");
                } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Now I'm wondering am I doing it right.

- Is this method written right for the purpose?
- Is there any mis-usages regarding `Mono` or `Flux`?

Comment: Hey Jin, could you maybe try to rework your indentation? It makes the code really hard to read and I'd guess it's because of the way the code is formatted here. Could you also give a little bit more information on what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @IEatBagels I want to pipe given `ResponseSpec` body and give caller an opportunity to read the body as a `ReadableByteChannel`. Thanks.